# Timezone in numeric values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

From this [API](http://www.astronomyapi.com/docs), it's asking for a timezone in a negative of positive value. What does this mean and how would I produce it in Rails 4?

```
tz  Time zone as negative of positive values. Ex: 6.5
```

From looking through the [Ruby Time API](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Time.html), I can't seem to make sense of where to look exactly. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is `gmt_offset` method, it returns difference between GMT and selected time zone (time object) in seconds. Just divide it by 3600 and there you go

Example

```
t = Time.gm(2000,1,1,20,15,1)   #=> 2000-01-01 20:15:01 UTC
t.gmt_offset                    #=> 0
l = t.getlocal                  #=> 2000-01-01 14:15:01 -0600
l.gmt_offset                    #=> -21600
```

Comment: @iamtoc - This answer looks good, but just make sure you change the source date and time to match whatever value you're passing to that API.  Local offsets will change based on the complexities of time zones, such as daylight saving time.  You should calculate the offset each time you call the API.

Comment: @MattJohnson great addition, why don't you extend my answer with it? :)